# Finding the Maximum Growth Ratio of Two Companies with Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm struggling with a question and I hope someone can help me out. The question is related to linear algebra and concerns two companies that can benefit from each other. The question provides the following linear relationship that describes the development of their respective turnovers:

$\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{1}}=A \mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}}$

Here, $\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}}$ represents the turnover for year $k$ for the two companies, and $A$ is a matrix given by:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1.1 & 0.15 \\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The question asks: at what ratio of turnover between the two companies is the growth rate maximum?

I tried to approach this question by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $A$. The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1.205$ and $\lambda_2 = 0.795$. How I found the eigenvalues was by solving the characteristic equation of the matrix $A$:

$$\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix of the same size as $A$, and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue we are looking for. In this case, the matrix $A$ is given by:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1.1 & 0.15 \\
0.2 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, we need to solve the characteristic equation:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1.1 - \lambda & 0.15 \\
0.2 & 0.9 - \lambda
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

Expanding the determinant, we get:

$$(1.1-\lambda)(0.9-\lambda)-0.15 \times 0.2 = 0$$

Simplifying the expression, we get:

$$\lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 0.69 = 0$$

Using the quadratic formula, we can solve for the eigenvalues:

$$\lambda = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

where $a=1$, $b=-2$, and $c=0.96.

Solving for $\lambda$, we get:

$$\lambda_1 = 0.8,\qquad \lambda_2 = 1.2$$

Therefore, the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ are $\lambda_1 = 0.8$ and $\lambda_2 = 1.2$.

To find the eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues, we need to solve the system of linear equations given by:

$$(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$$

where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue we are interested in, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $\mathbf{v}$ is the corresponding eigenvector.

Let's first find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 1.2$. We need to solve the system of equations:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1.1-1.2 & 0.15 \\
0.2 & 0.9-1.2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Simplifying the matrix equation, we get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.1 & 0.15 \\
0.2 & -0.3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This gives us two equations:

$$
-0.1v_1 + 0.15v_2 = 0
$$

$$
0.2v_1 - 0.3v_2 = 0
$$

We can solve for $v_1$ and $v_2$ by setting $v_1$ to a free variable, and solving for $v_2$ in terms of $v_1$:

$$
v_1 = t
$$

$$
v_2 = \frac{2}{3}t
$$

where $t$ is any non-zero constant. Therefore, the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 1.2$ is:

$$
\mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
t \\
\frac{2}{3}t
\end{bmatrix}
= t \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\frac{2}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We can choose any non-zero value for $t$, but it is common to choose $t=3$, which gives us the normalized eigenvector:

$$
\mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Similarly, we can find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_2 = 0.8$ by solving the system of equations:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1.1-0.8 & 0.15 \\
0.2 & 0.9-0.8
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Simplifying the matrix equation, we get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.3 & 0.15 \\
0.2 & 0.1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here to find the ratio of turnover that gives the maximum growth rate. Can someone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sidenote: $\mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}$ is not a normalized vector.